# Image Onclick change image javascript

Tags: javascript

Just a fast question. I'm using javascript for a gallery, it work's like that: I have the big images (sunglasses) and i have colors below it (simple colored circle image) when i click on the color it changes the sunglasses image to the other color. I found a way in javascript like that(and it's working).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function change() {
      var image = document.getElementById('iks8600A');
      image.src = ('assets/szemuveg/iks8600B.jpg');
        document.getElementById('link').href = 'assets/szemuveg/iks8600B.jpg';
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function back() {
      var image = document.getElementById('iks8600A');
      image.src = ('assets/szemuveg/iks8600A.jpg');
      document.getElementById('link').href = 'assets/szemuveg/iks8600A.jpg'
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function change2() {
      var image = document.getElementById('S8621A');
      image.src = ('assets/szemuveg/s8621A.png');
    }
    </script>
```

So i have to do it at every sunglasses picture and it will be a very long code. Is it the right way to do it? Or there is an easier way to do it?
Thanks for the helps/suggestions.

Comment: You probably want to learn about [arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) and [loops](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM).

Comment: You could put all the first images in a given folder and their corresponding replacement in another with the same name. That way you would deal with each image with the same code, passing your clicked element as a reference

Comment: I will try to do that and do some research. But if i leave it that way and i will have like a 100 code similar to that in my html will it be a problem?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you (or somebody else) will want to change something. Maybe in your case it wont be a problem but you should get used to use the good practices to avoid useless repetition.

Comment: Thanks Adrien. You helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I posted an answer to your problem, let me know if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
var imgUrls = {
    red : "path/to/redImg.jpg",
    blue : "path/to/blueImg.jpg",
    green : "path/to/greenImg.jpg",
    black : "path/to/blackImg.jpg"
};

function switchGlassesColor (color) {
    document.getElementById('iks8600A').src = imgUrls[color];
    document.getElementById('link').href = imgUrls[color];
}
```

Corresponding HTML:

```
<img id="iks8600A" alt="Sunglasses... Deal with it!"></img>
<img onclick="switchGlassesImage('red')" alt="RED SUNGLASSES, Omagad!"></img>
<img onclick="switchGlassesImage('blue')" alt="Blue singlasses, with a swag diesel effect"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Please, add your HTML code of these elements.

But if I understood you correctly - you can set an array of colors and images. E.G.:

```
imagesArray = [{color: 'red',  image: 'assets/szemuveg/iks8600A.jpg'},
               {color: 'blue', image: 'assets/szemuveg/iks8600B.jpg'}];
```

And after that you can use it in single function to change an image.